# Why is _tokenProvider.AccessToken always null in my RequestHandler in Blazor server-side?

Tags: .net, authentication, dependency-injection, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a server-side blazor app which makes requests to an external API. I am trying to attach an access token to an auth header to every API request. Following the microsoft docs on `ASP.NET Core Blazor Server additional security scenarios` I have the following code:

Pages/_Host.cshtml

```
@{
    var tokens = new InitialApplicationState()
    {
        AccessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("id_token"),
        RefreshToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("refresh_token")
    };
}
...
    <component type="typeof(App)" param-InitialState=tokens render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
```

App.razor

```
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public InitialApplicationState? InitialState { get; set; }

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        TokenProvider.AccessToken = InitialState?.AccessToken;
        TokenProvider.RefreshToken = InitialState?.RefreshToken;

        return base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
}
```

At this point, the microsoft docs suggest injecting the TokenProvider into a service that makes HTTP requests and grabbing the token from `TokenProvider.AccessToken` and putting it in an auth header.
I would rather not have to include that code in every service making HTTP requests (there are a lot) and instead I just want to add the token via a default RequestHandler.

RequestHandler.cs

```
    public class RequestHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        private readonly ILogger<RequestHandler> _logger;
        private readonly TokenProvider _tokenProvider;

        public RequestHandler(ILogger<RequestHandler> logger, TokenProvider tokenProvider)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _tokenProvider = tokenProvider;
        }

        protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var token = _tokenProvider.AccessToken;

            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
            return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

Here is the service config snippet:

```
            builder.Services.AddScoped<TokenProvider>();
            builder.Services.AddScoped<RequestHandler>();

            builder.Services.ConfigureAll<HttpClientFactoryOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.HttpMessageHandlerBuilderActions.Add(builder =>
                {
                    builder.AdditionalHandlers.Add(builder.Services.GetRequiredService<RequestHandler>());
                });
            });
```

The problem is that in my RequestHandler, _tokenProvider.AccessToken is always NULL. However, injecting TokenProvider into one of my services (i.e. WeatherForecaseService.cs), the token is there, as expected.

Why is the token always null in this RequestHandler? Alternatively, how can I attach the token to every request (without manually adding the code to every request). Do I have to rely on some Blazor local storage package?